# Не понимаю от чего зависит ляжет сайт или нет

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сайт

Вопрос скорее всего покажется глупым, но я правда не понимаю. Все же видели/слышали мем, что: "когда на сайт госуслуг зашло больше 10 человек: ..картинка..    ,и когда на сайт стима зашло 100.000": ..картинка... Так вот у меня вопрос: с чем это связано? От чего зависит ляжет сайт или нет, если зайдёт много пользователей?

Comment: От того, способны ли имеющиеся мощности серверов обработать поступающие запросы в разумные сроки ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Просто потому что в стиме круглые сутки сидят программисты и сисадмины, которые контролируют поток.
А в "госуслуги" просто брандмауэр настроен на конкретные айпи адреса.

upd: зависит от мощности серверов. Стим по-моему тоже был когда-то на уровне Госуслуг. Слабый и не мог обработать очень много запросов.

Answer (score 1):

От мощности самого сервера, от настройки веб сервера, от оптимизации самого кода веб страниц.